# Call php function with parameters from ajax (DataTable jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to call a php function with parameter from jQuery (DataTable), like above:

```
table = $('#tbl').DataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            [...]               
        //"ajax" : "users/list",
        //"data": {"id", "1"},
        "ajax": {
            "url": "users/list",
            "data": {
                "id": 1
            }
          },
            [...]
    });
```

php function (users.php):

```
    function list($id){
         [...]
    }
```

Error message: Missing argument 1 for users::list()

Comment: follow codeigniter's way of handling URI segments, its supposed to be `users/list/1` to actually feed the argument in your method thru URL

Comment: yes thats about it, you just concatenate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id = $('$control').val;
table = $('#tbl').DataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
        [...]               
    "ajax" : "users/list/" + id,
        [...]
});
```